# regex, multiline extract in R

Tags: regex, r, multiline

I am having some problems with deleting everything after the first occurrence of a pattern in R. I have imported the data with `paste(readLines(url), collapse="\n")`.

For example, my string is, `\"id=\"fruit_info\">\n<tr class='thead'>\n<th colspan=2>Strawberries</th></table>\n</tr>\n</table>\n<tr class`.

I want to remove everything after the first occurrence of `</table>`. What I want to see is;

`\"id=\"fruit_info\">\n<tr class='thead'>\n<th colspan=2>Strawberries</th>`

The methods I am trying do not seem to register the first `</table>` occurrence and not providing the intended results.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `sub("</table>.*", "", x)` (if `x` is your string)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using the inline `(?s)` modifier which forces the dot `.` to span across newline sequences.

```
sub('(?s)</table>.*', '', x, perl = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was having trouble understanding the spanning across newlines!

Comment: Hmm, just `sub("</table>.*", "", x)` worked for me. In which cases it will fail?

Comment: @DavidArenburg, in the case of it having newline sequences =) See here https://regex101.com/r/cV7nD7/1

Comment: I get that, but OP read it as one string `x <-"\"id=\"fruit_info\">\n<tr class='thead'>\n<th colspan=2>Strawberries</th></table>\n</tr>\n</table>\n<tr"`. In this case R doesn't treat it as a new line sequence, rather just some random character.

Comment: OP read the string in and collapsed by newline, therefore the string would have newline characters in it. But I can't clarify, but I know you need the dotall modifier to match across multiple newline sequences.

Comment: Yes, it does. And my code still works on the above mentioned `x`. Though never-mind, it seems like you've got what OP wants, so that doesn't matter anymore I guess.